# android NDK --converting C++ method to java mthod

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I'm developing an android app that extract the bag of word from any captured image 
I will use the opencv library for that purpose folliwing this [tutorial](http://www.app-solut.com/blog/2011/07/the-bag-of-words-model-in-opencv-2-2/)

Now I have a C++ method :
`void extractTrainingVocabulary(const path& basepath) {...}`
that I need it in my android activity

```
   void extractTrainingVocabulary(const path& basepath) {
for (directory_iterator iter = directory_iterator(basepath); iter
        != directory_iterator(); iter++) {
    directory_entry entry = *iter;

    if (is_directory(entry.path())) {

        cout << "Processing directory " << entry.path().string() << endl;
        extractTrainingVocabulary(entry.path());

    } else {

        path entryPath = entry.path();
        if (entryPath.extension() == ".jpg") {

            cout << "Processing file " << entryPath.string() << endl;
            Mat img = imread(entryPath.string());
            if (!img.empty()) {
                vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
                detector->detect(img, keypoints);
                if (keypoints.empty()) {
                    cerr << "Warning: Could not find key points in image: "
                            << entryPath.string() << endl;
                } else {
                    Mat features;
                    extractor->compute(img, keypoints, features);
                    bowTrainer.add(features);
                }
            } else {
                cerr << "Warning: Could not read image: "
                        << entryPath.string() << endl;
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

so following the `android NDK` tutorials 
I should declare this method like this :  `public native void extractTrainingVocabulary () ;`

My problem is how to do with the C++ argument `const path& basepath`? how to pass this argument in the java method

I hope that my question is clear for you 
Thanks

Comment: I'm new to C++ , but after googled this argument `const path& basepath` is a const reference so I don't know how to convert it , java don't use references

Comment: @nawara Java uses only references for everything (except for primitive types). But that's beside the point, with JNI you can only pass [JNI Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html), so you need to take for example a jstring in your JNI function, construct a `path` object (whatever that is) in the c implementation of that JNI function. Then use that object to call your existing c-function from within the JNI function.

Answer (score 2):

The first question is, what is the base type of `path` in C/C++ code, for example if this is String, so you need to declare the Java method with a String value as input.

```
class Dude{
public native void extractTrainingVocabulary(final String arg);
}
```

first compile the dude class with `javac Dude.java`
then you need the header file, pass the generated class file to `javah Dude`, then `javah` will give you a header file, something like this.

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Dude */

#ifndef _Included_Dude
#define _Included_Dude
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Dude
 * Method:    extractTrainingVocabulary
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Dude_extractTrainingVocabulary
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

here in above code, the `jstring` is pointing to the Java input argument for the method, may you need to use that guy.
the next step is, implement the `Java_Dude_extractTrainingVocabulary` function and call the actual method.

Comment: now It is not a string , path is a C++ class 

I edited my question to add `extarctTrainingVocabulary ` implementation

Comment: no problem dude, it doesn't matter what is the type of Path is here class/struct/etc.., so the question is what does it need to be created?! if it needs two int, one String and a byte[] data, so you would change the java method declaration to do so, but remember only pass the data which is really needed to be passed from the java application, no default values, constant, etc...

Comment: If I understand your response , I should pass to my java method what the C++ method need and what the `Path `( whatever its type ) need? 
it is not necessary that the 2 methods have the same arguments?

Comment: yes of course buddy, you need to know about the requirement for creating the `Path` type, if it needs 2 integers, so pass the integers by the java application to the c/c++ code, then in native code create the actual type with that two integers.